# Wrong number in sections

Tags: sectioning

I have a problem: my file has the following numbering among chapters and sections:

```
Chapter 1 ... 
1.1 title section ... 
1.2 title section ... 
3 title section
```

Why didn't LaTeX write `1.3 title section`?

Even in the next chapter the numbering is wrong: it outputs the first section with the number 4 instead of 2.1.

Comment: Sounds like you messed with some counters. Impossible to say without a minimal working example.

Comment: How can I make you an example? I mean, the index is working good, but the numbering is wrong:

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Here is the link to learn more... https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks

Comment: I can't understand how to do a nice example, I am italian and don't know exactly how to proceed, if I post the packages they are all in mess

Comment: The problem is that before an example the section numbering is working good, but after that example all crush and I have what i said

Comment: Ah, you're starting to provide some crucial extra tidbits of information. Tell us please what the "example" is about and, in particular, how it is defined. It sure sounds like the example command (or is it an environment) is the culprit that's messing with the numbering system for section-level headers...

Comment: Well i defined the example in this way: \newtheorem{es}{Esempio}[chapter]. In the main i call it with the command \begin{es} [....] \end{es} and if I type \section{..} here, the number of the section is 3 instead of 1.3

Comment: It's starting to get warmer. :-) Do provide some more information, please. For instance, which document class do you employ, and which package(s) do you employ to create theorem-like environments? And, to verify that it really is the `es` environment that's interfering with the section-level numbering system, do go find out what happens if you comment out the code for the `es` enviroment in section 1.2. In particular, is proper numbering of section-level headers restored if the `es` environment in the body of section 1.2 is commented out and the document is recompiled?

Comment: I am using the document class book and to create the theorek-like environments i used the packages caption, tocbibind, hyperref. And if i comment the es I have the same problem, but if I comment all the section the problem is restored

Comment: OK, so you have established that it's *not* the `es` environment *per se* that's causing the sectioning numbering to get messed up. So it must be something else, right? Sadly, my psychic powers are absolutely worthless. Unless and until you edit your posting to provide actually relevant information about your document, I'm in no position to venture a guess as to what's causing the situation you say you're encountering.

Comment: Ok, I can upload the document, but if I put the section before a system it works, after the system it doesn't, so maybe it's the system the problem.